# performSegue creates two view controllers

Tags: ios, swift, segue

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)
    self.delegate = segue.destination as? MenuViewController
    print("check_1", self.delegate)
}


@IBAction func openMenu(_ sender: Any) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "openMenu", sender: sender)
    print("check_2", self.delegate)
}
```

My main `ViewController` updates values while `MenuViewController` displays these values. Each time `ViewController` values are updated, it calls `self.delegate.updateValues` in `MenuViewController`. I transition between the two `ViewControllers` through buttons.

My problem is that it seems like the `MenuViewController` displayed is a different object than the one stored in `self.delegate` inside `ViewController`. Printing the check statements:

```
check_1 Optional(<Menu.MenuViewController: 0x10161ca10>)
check_2 Optional(<Menu.MenuViewController: 0x10161ca10>)
check_1 Optional(<Menu.MenuViewController: 0x10161dd10>)
```

May I ask how do I make sure only one instance of `MenuViewController` is created and stored in `self.delegate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a segue to a storyboard, if you hook up the segue to a specific button/`IBAction`, you don't need to call `performSegue` manually, it will be automatically called for you.

You have 2 segues executed, since both the storyboard executes the segue and then you also do it from code by calling `performSegue`.

`performSegue` should only be used when your segue isn't directly hooked up to a UI event or if you need to conditionally perform a segue - such as when you have a login button, where depending on the network response, you might execute an error or a login segue.